# Get value on key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I have JS select. I need to make onKeyPress function witch will return me a true value, that start on character I press.

I have array of values, it's span values, so i try to grab them with JQuery `.text`. What i grab it's big array without right spaces, like that:

`Republic AdygeyaRepublic AltaiAltaisky krayAmur regionArkhangelsk regionAstrahan regionRepublic Bashkorstan`    and more...

My keypress function:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
                if (e.which == 33) {
                    var $item = $wrapperItems.find('span');
                    var $mass = $item.text();
                    if ($mass == $mass.toUpperCase()) {
                        alert("$mass");
                    }
                    alert(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
                    console.log($mass);
                }
            });
```

Sorry for grammar mistakes and thanks for attention.

Comment: What is it that you try to achieve and where do you get stuck exactly?

Comment: I try to grab right value from array, when i press key. But my array(actually text) without spaces and it's ignore function .toUpperCase()

Comment: I don't understand what value you're comparing? is it a value that comes from an input box?

Comment: How are you capturing the value? When you declare `$mass = $item.text()` you get that big string. When you do `$mass == $mass.toUpperCase()` it will never be true because you're making the entire string uppercase. I think you're trying to compare a value you don't fetch. [Here's a jsFiddle I mockedup](http://jsfiddle.net/xxBmz/) outlining the core principles of how to do this.

Comment: it's split to wrong array: like `[Republic] , [AdygeyaRepublic]` , but i need `[Republic Agydea]` and so..